# Какой паттерн выбать для реализации многоэтапной регистрации на PHP

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть задача отрефакторить регистрацию на большом легаси проекте.
Регистрация состоит из нескальких(около 20) шагов. Очередность шагов различная в зависимости от многих условий. Регистрация может начинаться из разных мест, может пропускать шаги, иногда может возвращаться на предыдущий шаг и может прийти в один и тот же шаг из нескольких других. И тд.

Сейчас в коде страшный ад из условий статусов и редиректов. После прохождения шага в поле в базе `status` устанавливается новое значение и по-этому статусу мы понимаем на каком шаге находимся сейчас. Кроме статуса в некоторых шагах используются дополнительные поля и шаг определяется по нескольким переменным.

Сначала я начал реализовывать все в виде цепочки шагов. И выглядело это примерно так:

```
$chain = new Chain();
$chain->add(new Step('first_step_status', '/registration/step1'));
$chain->add(new Step('second_step_status', '/registration/step2'));
$chain->add(new Step('third_step_status', '/registration/step3'));
//код контроллера 
//определяем текущий шаг
$current = $chain->getByStatus($status);

//переходим на следующий шаг
$this->redirect($current->getNext()->getUrl());
```

В этом решении мне очень понравилась наглядность какой шаг идет за каким. Легко добавить новый шаг между двумя существующими. Но я не смог придумать как сделать это гибко, ведь не всегда из шага1 мы переходим на шаг2, и не всегда шаг определяется одним полем `status`.

Потом я решил все переписать и реализовать паттерн State.
У меня была фабрика, которая в зависимости от объекта регистрации клиента, смотрит на все возможные статусы и тд и возвращает текущий объект состояния. В каждом объекте состояние есть метод возвращающий текущий url и метод для перехода на следующий шаг. 
В этом решении было всё чего не хватало в решении с цепочками. Но и не было плюсов из прошлого решения. Но не было наглядности, что бы понять очередность шагов нужно очень постараться надо зайти в фабрику, потом зайти в класс шага, посмотреть на метода перехода на следующий шаг, потом опять в фабрику и тд.

И я не могу придумать как сделать и наглядно и гибко. Я думал как-то объеденить эти два подхода, но не знаю пока как.

Может быть кто-то решал подобную задачу и есть другие решения?

Comment: workflow symfony например такое помогает решить, но не подскажу с шаблоном, еще ключевое слово finite state machine

Comment: @Ghost Спасибо большое! workflow symfony - это то что надо. Осталось только реализовать его на yii1